# Vertical Hamburger side navigation bar is creating a blank space on the right side of the screen. Shown only in mobile version

Tags: html, css, navbar, space

I have a responsive hamburger side navigation bar on the upper right of my website. When user clicks, the sub-menus appear vertically. There is no problem when viewed in PC, but, when viewed in mobile, there is a blank space on the right side of the screen, as shown below:

[image]

I searched everywhere to find the answer, such as adjusting the width of the screen, placing the width as 100%, writing body and HTML {overflow-x: hidden;}, etc..

After doing more research, I finally found out that the blank space is a vertical hamburger navigation bar. Simply put, if a user clicks on the hamburger menu, the vertical sub-menu is sliding to from right to left.

If I write width: 100% in .nav-links in @media of CSS, more blank space is created on the right since the side navigation bar would slide full screen from right to left.

I'm wondering whether there is any way I can have this responsive vertical hamburger side-menu without having any of the spacing issue?

The issue belongs to here in CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 950px) {
   .nav-links {
   position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        height: 92vh;
        top: 10vh;
        background-color: black;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 40%;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        padding-right: 2em;
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
        z-index: 99999;
     }
```

Below is a full-code for my website:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="monday.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>J[a]son</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <div class = "logo">
            <h4>J[a]son</h4>
        </div>
        <ul class = "nav-links">
            <li>
                <a href="#">HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">PHOTOGRAPHY</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="photography_colour.html">Colour</a></li>
                    <li><a href="photography_black.html">Black</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">CODING</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class= "burger">
            <div class="line1"></div>
            <div class="line2"></div>
            <div class="line3"></div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="testing.js"></script>
    <div class="main_car_wrapper">
        <img class="main_car" src="Photos/main_car1.jpg" alt="car" width="100%" height="100%"/>

    </div>
           <!--<p>June, 2020. Sunshine Coast, BC, Canada </p>-->
    <div class ="bottom">
        <div class = "logos">
            <a href="https://github.com/j-ahn94" target="_blank" class="fa fa-github"></a>
            <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/14266888/jason-a" target="_blank" class="fa fa-stack-overflow"></a>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/jasonja-ahn/" target="_blank" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
            <p id = "paragraph">TESTING</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html {
    min-height: 100vh;
}

* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: black !important; /*rgb(241, 233, 233);*/
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
    
}

nav {
    display: flex !important;
    justify-content: space-between;
    /*padding-right: 2em;*/
    padding-left: 2em;
    padding-top: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 1.5em;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 8vh;
    background-color: black;
    /*font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;*/
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.logo {
    background-color: black;
    color: rgb(240, 235, 235);
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}

.nav-links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 30%;
}

.nav-links li {
    list-style: none;
}

.nav-links a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11px;
    /*padding: 5px 5px;*/
}

.nav-links a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.burger {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div {
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1430px) {
    .nav-links {
        width: 40%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:950px) {
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    body, html {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    
    .nav-links {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        height: 92vh;
        top: 10vh;
        background-color: black;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 40%;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        padding-right: 2em;
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
        z-index: 99999;
    }
    .nav-links li {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .burger {
        display: block;
        padding-right: 1em;
    }
    .sub-menu {
        position: relative;
    }
    .carousel-control-prev {
        padding-top: 5em;
    }

    .carousel-control-next {
        padding-top: 5em;
    }

    .carousel-item {
        padding-top: 6em;
    }
    
    .logos { 
        padding-bottom: 0em;
    }
}

.nav-active {
    transform: translate(0%);https://ahweb.org.uk/car.png
}

.main_car_wrapper {
    background-image: url(https://ahweb.org.uk/car.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: contain;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 6em;
}

@keyframes navLinkFade {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(50px);
    }
    to {
        opacity :1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}

.toggle .line1 {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
}

.toggle .line2 {
    opacity: 0;
}

.toggle .line3 {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -6px);

}

.sub-menu {
    display: none;
}

.sub-menu li a {
    /*display: block;*/
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    background: rgb(221, 215, 215);
    white-space: nowrap;
    top: 40px;
    left: 25px;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-top: 1px;
}

.sub-menu li a:hover{
    background: rgb(10, 10, 10);
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;   
}

li:hover ul {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
}

li:hover li {
    float: none;
    font-size: 8px;
}

li:hover a {
    background: rgb(5, 5, 5);
}

li:hover li a:hover {
    background: rgb(19, 18, 18);
}

.bottom {
    margin-top: auto; 
}

.logos {
    display: flex !important;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: black;
}

.logos a {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.logos a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.carousel-inner p {
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.carousel-inner {
    background-color: black;
}

.carousel-inner img {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50vw;
    max-height: auto;
    align-items: center;
}

/*.carousel-item {
    height: 300px
}*/

.carousel-control-prev-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5 2.5-2.5-1.5-1.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.carousel-control-next-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M2.75 0l-1.5 1.5 2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.5 1.5 4-4-4-4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

JS:

```
const navSlide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
  const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
  const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');
  //Toggle Nav
  burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    //Toggle Nav
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');

    //Animate Links
    navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
      if(link.style.animation) {
        link.style.animation = ''
      } else {
          link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.2s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.5}s`;
      }
    });
    //Burger Animation
    burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
  });
  //Animate Links
  
}

navSlide();
```

Comment: Use your browser inspector and check if there is any unnecessary margin or padding. Open the inspector `ctrl + shift + i` and then press `ctrl + shift + c`. Hover your mouse over the hamburger and check. If any margin/padding is present (yellow/purple highlight), target that element and remove it.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. I already did and it routes me to .nav-links in @media. Deleting the width: 40% will fix the issue, but the problem is I won't be able to see the vertical nav if I did it..not sure how to fix it.

Comment: I copied all your code and run it in my browser. But it didn't produce the gap. Could you please check again. Maybe its because of  horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Hello, if you don't mind, my website is www.jsonahn.com. If  you quickly Inspect and view it in mobile version, you will probably see the vertical and bottom gap.

Comment: There's no space to the right of hamburger icon. But yes, there is a gap between the img and footer because the body is a **flexbox**. To remove the gap, either make it **block** or set `min-height: 0`.